# When will my device get Android L?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

I know we don't have a codename yet, but I'm already seeing rumors about what devices will get the next version of Android, so I've created a "When will my device..." Community Wiki question.

[When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75684)

As we get more information (especially the codename and version number) let's be sure to update the question and answer.